# Sampling a specific age distribution from a dataset

Tags: r, distribution, population

Suppose I have a dataset with 1,000,000 observations. Variables are age, race, gender. This dataset represents the whole US.

How can I draw a sample of 1,000 people from this dataset, given a certain age distribution? E.g. I want this datset with 1000 people distributed like this:

0.3 * Age 0 - 30

0.3 * Age 31 - 50

0.2 * Age 51 - 69

0.2 * Age 70 - 100

Is there a quick way to do it? I already created a sample of 1000 people with the desired age distribution, but how do I combine that now with my original dataset?

As an example, this is how I have created the population distribution of Maine:

```
set.seed(123)
library(magrittr) 

    popMaine <- data.frame(min=c(0, 19, 26, 35, 55, 65), max=c(18, 25, 34, 54, 64, 113), prop=c(0.2, 0.07, 0.11, 0.29, 0.14, 0.21))

    Mainesample <- sample(nrow(popMaine), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=popMaine$prop)

    Maine <- round(popMaine$min[Mainesample] + runif(1000) * (popMaine$max[Mainesample] - popMaine$min[Mainesample])) %>% data.frame()

    names(Texas) <- c("Age")
```

Now I don't know how to bring this together with my other dataset which has the whole US population... I'd appreciate any help, I am stuck for quite a while now...

Answer (score 1):

Below are four different approaches. Two use functions from, respectively, the `splitstackshape` and `sampling` packages, one uses base `mapply`, and one uses `map2` from the `purrr` package (which is part of the `tidyverse` collection of packages).

First let's set up some fake data and sampling parameters:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(156)
df = data.frame(age=sample(0:100, 1e6, replace=TRUE))

# Add a grouping variable for age range
df = df$age.groups = cut(df$age, c(0,30,51,70,Inf), right=FALSE)

# Total number of people sampled
n = 1000

# Named vector of sample proportions by group
probs = setNames(c(0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2), levels(df$age.groups))
```

Using the above sampling parameters, we want to sample `n` total values with a proportion `probs` from each age group.

#### Option 1: `mapply`

`mapply` can apply multiple arguments to a function. Here, the arguments are (1) the data frame `df` split into the four age groupings, and (2) `probs*n`, which gives the number of rows we want from each age group:

```
df.sample = mapply(a=split(df, df$age.groups), b=probs*n, 
       function(a,b) {
         a[sample(1:nrow(a), b), ]
       }, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

`mapply` returns a list with of four data frames, one for each stratum. Combine this list into a single data frame:

```
df.sample = do.call(rbind, df.sample)
```

Check the sampling:

```
table(df.sample$age.groups)
```

> ```
> [0,30)  [30,51)  [51,70) [70,Inf) 
>    300      300      200      200
> ```

#### Option 2: `stratified` function from the `splitstackshape` package

The `size` argument requires a named vector with the number of samples from each stratum.

```
library(splitstackshape)

df.sample2 = stratified(df, "age.groups", size=probs*n)
```

#### Option 3: `strata` function from the `sampling` package

This option is by far the slowest.

```
library(sampling)

# Data frame must be sorted by stratification column(s)
df = df[order(df$age.groups),]

sampled.rows = strata(df, 'age.groups', size=probs*n, method="srswor")

df.sample3 = df[sampled.rows$ID_unit, ]
```

#### Option 4: `tidyverse` packages

`map2` is like `mapply` in that it applies two arguments in parallel to a function, in this case the `dplyr` package's `sample_n` function. `map2` returns a list of four data frames, one for each stratum, which we combine into a single data frame with `bind_rows`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df.sample4 = map2(split(df, df$age.groups), probs*n, sample_n) %>% bind_rows
```

#### Timings

```
library(microbenchmark)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>        expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
>      mapply   86.77215  110.82979  156.66855  123.95275  145.25115  486.2078    10  a 
>      strata 5028.42933 5541.40442 5709.16796 5699.50711 5845.69921 6467.7250    10   b
>  stratified   38.33495   41.76831   89.93954   45.43525   79.18461  408.2346    10  a 
>   tidyverse   71.48638  135.49113  143.12011  142.86866  155.72665  192.4174    10  a
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been tremendously helpful! I didn't try all methods but will do so soon

Comment: Ok one follow-up question: Along the way, I lose the other variables of my original dataset - how can I make this work to have them included in my sample of 1000?